# Display 0 results in the left join query

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I count the number of participants in the event_participants table and display also the event_title with zero results. This is my table

```
event_title
id | name  
1  | New York 
2  | Canada   


event_participants

id | event_title_id | name
1  | 1              | Jon
2  | 1              | Mike
```

This is my query

```
SELECT count( * ) AS count
FROM event_participants AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_title AS t2 ON t1.event_title_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.event_title_id
```

I am getting a correct result but does not display the 0 results.
I should be getting a result like this

```
New York | 2
Canada   | 0
```

Comment: How are you sure that you are getting a correct result??? Are you using PHP??? If yes then show us your PHP code..!

Answer (score 1):

In place of `*` use `t2.id` it will work

```
SELECT count(t2.id) AS count
FROM event_participants AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_title AS t2 ON t1.event_title_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t1.event_title_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your group by is the problem. 
you are grouping by the `event_title_id` where you dont have the id `2`.

What you should do is a group by the `name` of the first table.

```
SELECT count( * ) AS count
FROM event_participants AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_title AS t2 ON t1.event_title_id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.name
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

Change your query like below to get desired output:

```
SELECT count(t2.id) AS count
FROM event_title AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_participants AS t2 ON t2.event_title_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id

//To retrieve title also

SELECT t1.title,count(t2.id) AS count
FROM event_title AS t1
LEFT JOIN event_participants AS t2 ON t2.event_title_id = t1.id
GROUP BY t1.id
```